# Splitting a number vector in R

Tags: r

The date in my dataset is written in monthdate format. Eg: 12th May is written as 512. I want to split it into month-date.

```
x <- 512
```

I want:

```
x <- 5-12
```

Comment: Are there leading zeroes in the days? How is 3rd May written, `53` or `503`?

Comment: How do you know if `121` means December 1st or January 21?

Comment: @Gregor 503 will be 3rd May. Leading zeroes for days but not months.

Comment: @Tim 121 would mean 21st January.

Comment: I found a code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's still worth, here is a possibility using `gsub`

```
ss <- c(512, 503, 121, 1212);
gsub("^(\\d+)(\\d{2})$", "\\1-\\2", as.character(ss))
#[1] "5-12"  "5-03"  "1-21"  "12-12"
```

Or to convert to `Date`

```
as.Date(gsub("^(\\d+)(\\d{2})$", "\\1-\\2", as.character(ss)), format = "%m-%d")
#[1] "2018-05-12" "2018-05-03" "2018-01-21" "2018-12-12"
```

Comment: Does the same code work for months with 2 digits as well?

Comment: @user9941892 Yes, it works with two digit months as well. I've included an example in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another variant with `sub` which does not use capture groups:

```
x <- 121
sub("(?<=[1-9]|1[0-2])(?=\\d{2})", "-", x, perl=TRUE)

[1] "1-21"
```

### Demo